# How can I overload a member function from an instance of a class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

I want to make a class where there is a function that is called automatically, to process information stored within this classes instance.

However each instance has different values and possibly a different way for that content to be handeled.

Therefore I need something simmilar to constructor overloading but in a member function. Where every instance can overload the default function or leave it up to the default to handle the input.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Can you not pass that function into the constructor as a parameter? std::function to the rescue!

Comment: @Bathsheba I dont have to pass it as a parameter

Comment: I know you don't. But you might *want* to.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a separate class for the variable behavior `Callable` describes the local data relating to the function, and by being a class, can be derived.

```
class Callable {
public:
    int m_Value;
    Callable(int value) : m_Value(value)
    {

    }
    void operator()( int val1, double val2 /* whatever makes sense */ ) {

    }
};
```

Using the function operator `void operator()( ...... )` we create a way of making variables of type Callable to look like a function.

```
class Variable {
public:
    Callable myFunction;
    Variable(const Callable & howToCall, /* some more stuff */) :
        myFunction(howToCall)
    { /* stuff */
    }
    void aFunction(int data, double value ) {
        myFunction( data,  value);
    }
};
```

When calling `aFunction` the current value of `myFunction` is called.

Finally `Variable` can change which function it calls, by modifying the value of myFunction....

```
 myFunction = Callable( /* new parameters */ );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Call Functions in Constructor with if else condition
like:

```
class abc{
 abc(){
         if username == "member 1"
             functioncall();
         else
             functioncall();
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you need some virtual construction emulation. There is a simple C/C++ way to do it.

```
    // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A; 
typedef void (*cb)(A*);


struct A
{
    int m_a;

    static void foo(A* aref)
    {
       std::cout << "Print a: " <<  aref->m_a << "\n";   
    }


    A(cb b=foo)
    {
        m_a = 100;
        b(this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

}
```

It is not very clear, but still does the trick.